# fixing errors on a program to call methods in java

Tags: java, methods, parameters

The following program contains 9 errors. Correct the errors and submit a working version of the program. The corrected version of the program should produce the following output:

x = 10.01 and y = 8.0
x = 10.01 and y = 867.5309
The value from main is: 867.5309
z = 5

I have already made some changes on this, but I can figure out why x and y aren't being called.

```
public class Oops3 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double y = 867.5309;
        double x = 10.01;
        printer(double x, double y);
        printer(x);
        printer(y);
        System.out.println("z = " + z);
}

public static void printer(double x, double y) {
    int z = 5;
    System.out.println("x = " + double x + " and y = " + double y);
    System.out.println("The value from main is: " + y);
}
```

}

Comment: Why are you calling a method that jas two parameters with one?

Comment: welcome to stack overflow, Please read [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this: (not sure how many changes you have already made)

```
public class Oops3 {

public static void printer(double x, double y) {
        System.out.println("x = " +  x + " and y = " +  y);
        System.out.println("The value from main is: " + y);}

public static void main(String[] args) {

            int z = 5;
            double y = 867.5309;
            double x = 10.01;
            System.out.println("x= " + x + " and y = 8.0");
            printer( x,y);
            System.out.println("z = " + z);

}}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following is the working code you are looking for

```
public class Oops3 
{
public static void printer(double x, double y, int z) {
    System.out.println("x = " + x + " and y = " + y);
System.out.println("The value from main is: " + y);
    System.out.println("z = " + z);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Oops3 O=new Oops3();
    double y = 867.5309;
    double x = 10.01;
int z = 5;
    O.printer(x, y, z);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This code worked for me

```
public class Oops3 {
public static void main(String [] args) {
    Oops3 i = new Oops3();
    double bubble = 867.5309;
    double x = 10.01;
    double y = 8.0;
    int z = 5;
    i.printer(x, y);
    i.printer(x, bubble);
    System.out.println("The value from main is: " + bubble);
    System.out.println("z = " + z);
}

public static void printer(double x, double y) {
    System.out.println("x = " +  x + " and y = " + y);
}
}
```